# how to run code in the UI thread calling it from the others ones

Tags: ios

In Android there are several ways to run some code in the main thread from others ones:

```
 1. Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable r)
 2. new Handler.post(Runnable r);
 3. View.post
```

What are the analogues in iOS?

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    });
```

Something else?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The preferred way nowadays is using GCD, with the code you quoted in your question:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Your code to run on the main queue/thread
});
```

If you prefer using a more Object-Oriented approach than GCD, you may also use an `NSOperation` (like an `NSBlockOperation`) and add it to the `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]`.

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
    // Your code to run on the main queue/thread
 }];
```

*This does quite the same thing as `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), …)`, has the advantage of being more Objective-C/POO oriented that the plain C GCD function, but has the drawback of needing to allocate memory for creating the `NSOperation` objects, whereas you can avoid it using plain C and GCD.*

---

I recommend using GCD, but there are other ways, like those two which allow you to call a selector (method) on a given object from the main thread:

- `- (void)performSelectorOnMainThread:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait` (method of NSObject so it can be called on any object)
- Send `- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector target:(id)target argument:(id)anArgument order:(NSUInteger)order modes:(NSArray *)modes` on the `[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]`

But those solutions are not as flexible as the GCD or `NSOperation` ones, because they only let you call existing methods (so your object has to have a method that already exists and does what you want to perform), whereas GCD or `-[NSOperationQueue addOperationWithBlock:]` allows you to pass arbitrary code (using the block).

Comment: Note that instead of `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]`, you can simply write `NSOperationQueue.mainQueue`.

Comment: Or in Swift-speak:
```DispatchQueue.main.async { code here }```

Answer (score 5):

Swift 5+ example

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // UI code
}


DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
    // UI code
}
```